# Change 'SKU' as bulk using Magmi or other

Tags: product, magmi, sku

I have those kind of SKU products

ABC-001-NM

ABC-002-NM

ABC-003-NM

And I want to change the SKU like that

ABC-001

ABC-002

ABC-003

I have a lot of products so I need to change as bulk way

I don't want to change database directly

and looking for using Magmi or other fast way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you should make a backup just in case, or dump the values and comment the `->save()`) :

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 

if(class_exists('Mage'))
{
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like', '%-NM%'));
    if(count($products) > 0)
    {
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            $product->setSku(str_replace('-NM', '', $product->getSku()));
            try{
                $product->save();
            } catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : You have to palce this file at the Magento's root folder. Otherwise, change the way you call `app/Mage.php`

Comment: glad it helped :)